# setting maxFormContentSize in jetty/solr

Tags: solr, jetty

I have updated maxFormContentSize in jetty.xml under etc directory but it still returns with the same old default value ,200000.
Why it is not reflecting new limit ?

Comment: Found a solution for this issue?

Comment: yes, solution to this is you have to add two properties into jetty connector configuration in jetty.xml  file.

Answer (score 5):

I found following solution.you have to add two properties into jetty connector configuration in jetty.xml  file,requestHeaderSize and requestBufferSize.

```
<Call name="addConnector">
<Arg>
<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector">
<Set name="host"><SystemProperty name="jetty.host" /></Set>
<Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8983"/></Set>
<Set name="maxIdleTime">300000</Set>
<Set name="lowResourceMaxIdleTime">1500</Set>
<Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
<Set name="requestHeaderSize">1000000</Set>
<Set name="requestBufferSize">1000000</Set>
</New>
</Arg>
</Call>
```